# Delphi XE7 listbox on Android - Items evenly divided on the screen

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

I am using a listbox in an application with Delphi XE7 and need to put 9 items in split screen evenly as this image:

[image: Image showing what needs to be done]

I do not know if I'm using the correct component but I can not make this division. Any idea how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a TGridPanelLayOut

see [example](http://community.embarcadero.com/index.php/article/articles-tutorials/151-ui/955-mobile-user-interface-design-home-screen-navigation)